# Cloning an MVC Solution - artifacts of old solution appearing in new solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I copied and pasted an entire solution locally (BEFORE.sln), renamed files/references to AFTER.sln, built, and then remapped my workspace and checked in.  Everything is working, except now I experience the following:

- When I publish AFTER.sln to Azure (right-click > Publish), I get AFTER.sln's changes as well as BEFORE.sln's files that I have deleted in AFTER.sln project.
- When I open BEFORE.sln in visual studio and then build/run AFTER.sln, some very weird combo build is happening where my old project's CSS/JS are being built into my new project, resulting in some very odd UI.
- In Azure, inspecting the generated MVC bundle shows files from BEFORE.sln, even though these files are NOWHERE in AFTER.sln, nor are they even on my local computer anymore.

There are no references to BEFORE.sln in AFTER.sln anywhere as far as I can tell.  I've cleaned my workspaces, even tried to build/publish on another computer and I'm still getting artifacts from the old project showing up in Azure.

What could be causing this bugginess after cloning a solution and publishing?  It's like the "publish" operation is using some kind of server workspace that the old project used too.

Comment: Have you tried to delete bin/obj folders from the after.sln project?

Comment: How many projects are in your AFTER.sln? Can you just create a AFTER-new.sln with only the AFTER projects and see if you get the same deployment issue?